# Use of "range" and "etc"

Tags: lists

When I use the word "range", can I end my list with "etc."?

Here is my concrete sentence:
"These data sets range from transport to tourism, fishery, forestry, and agriculture etc."

Comment: Yes, you can. The question is: what's the point? It adds nothing.

Comment: Good point. Ill remove it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"etc." is short for "et cetera", which is a Latin expression that means *and other things*.

By saying that the data includes a wide range of different things, you're already implying that the list which follows necessarily omits items for brevity and isn't exhaustive. So you don't need "etc.".

Personally, I'd probably omit the "etc." altogether and try to express what the data sets actually cover in a general way. For instance, instead of giving *examples* of what the data covers, say what it actually covers:

> These data sets cover major industries outside the service sector, for the years 2007 through 2012.

Answer (score -1):

The problem here is that you shouldn't be using the word "range" at all. A range is something that has finite limits. "Ranging from A to Z" works because A is the beginning of the alphabet and Z is the end. Or "ranging from A to C and F to M" would work.

You have a list, not a range, and you are providing examples from within that list. I would therefore use the word "include", making your sentence: "These data sets include transport, tourism, fishery, forestry, agriculture etc."

Comment: This solves my problem, thanks for making a good point. Shouldn't there be a comma between "agriculture" and "etc."